# How to set up a web site to receive XML via HTTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, http

Web developer newbie question (I am otherwise fluent in C#!):

I need to set up a web site (ASP.NET/C#) that can receive XML posts via HTTP.  I haven't the first clue of where to start.  Create web site?  Web page?  Web service?  WCF?  Can you self-host it, or must it be on IIS?  How/where do you catch the post event?

Comment: You mean XML-RPC? Or arbitrary XML files?

Comment: @fesesjoco: arbitrary XML posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple option is to create a simple web application with a generic handler (.ashx) file.  These were designed to accept get/post requests and completely simplify the page life cycle.

They have 1 entry method and are very easy to extend to handle the processing you want.

I'd go this route before bothering with WCF or ASMX services as the payload can literally be anything without having to change bindings.

Comment: Sounds like KISS is the way to go - please can you provide links to an example of how this would be done?

Comment: @Shaul: here's an interesting example to get you started: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RestServicesInASPNET2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple approaches. WCF REST is probably the best one. You can find a good introduction on it in the [MSDN Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx). Please note that in the 4.0 version of WCF (currently the latest one) there are some improvements. For details, search for "Improved REST Support" in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx).

Here are replies to your individual questions:

1. "Create web site? Web page? Web service? WCF?"
   There are multiple approaches you can use. Creating a web site, or an .aspx page inside an existent ASP .Net site, or even a HTTP handler are all valid options. If you are going to go on this path you will have to handle much of the service internal works yourself. For example you will have to handle the data serialization / deserialization yourself by using the DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer classes.
   However, as mentioned above, WCF REST would probably be the best option since it is especially built for situations like the one you describe.
2. "Can you self-host it, or must it be on IIS?"
   For ASP .Net web sites or HTTP handlers you will need IIS. For WCF REST you can both self-host or deploy on IIS.
3. "How/where do you catch the post event?"
   For an ASP .Net page, you can use the Page_Load event to process the request. You should access the Request member of the current page to check the HTTP method of the request and all the other elements related to it. You can find all the members of the Request class in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx).
   For WCF REST you do not have to bother on implementing the POST handler since it will be automatically implemented by WCF for you.

As a final note, not directly related to your question, if you are going to develop any kind of service on top of HTTP, you might consider using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), which is an indispensable tool for these kind of services.

**Update**
Just a short architectural note related to choosing your approach based on the complexity of your service. As I detailed when answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345575/why-use-a-web-service-with-ajax-over-a-static-page-method/4345664#4345664) question, if you already have a web site to which you want to add a very simple API functionality (simple == just a few methods), you should probably do it using ASP .Net pages or HTTP handlers. WCF is a lot more powerful and better suited for more complex services, but might be a little intimidation to initially if you don't have much experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with either WCF or an asmx web service.  The easiest is probably to use ajax and an IIS hosted WCF service.

Here is a basic example just using the XmlHttp object: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/02/18/how-to-consume-wcf-using-ajax-without-asp-net.aspx

Here is one with JQuery:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx

Conversely, you can use the AJAX enabled WCF Service template and the ASP.NET script manager, but I have not been as successful at that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their answers!

Ultimately I decided to use a synchronous HTTP handler, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx).